# Subdivision Surface creates only one level of subdiv in 3.6

Tags: modifiers, versions

I got this strange behaviour of the SubSurf Modifier and the Multires modifier in 3.6. Until 3.5 everything works as expected.

I saw that lots of people don't have any issue, and I didn't find anything similar on the web.

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Windows 11, i9 13900, RTX 4070Ti, 64 GB RAM, drivers updated, it happens both with GPU Subdiv preference turned On and Off.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: That image is too small to see what you are doing. Could you please explain the exact sequence of events you're using?

Comment: On default cube I add the subdiv, crank up both Viewport and render levels to 6, then apply the modifier. I get a cube subdivided une time instead of 6. Then I repeat the sequence and I get another single level of subdiv.

Comment: That works absolutely fine here with the subdiv modifier under Blender 3.6.4 and Windows 10. I've not checked the multires modifier because I've never used it and don't know how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know that it's a problem of my config, but I've tried to turn off addons, set factory pref, reinstall from scratch, 3.6.3 and 3.6.4, always the same problem, I don't understand what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Putting a second modifier on it when you've already applied one with 6 levels is going to give you problems anyway because of the number of verts it's trying to process. In fact blender locks up and eventually crashes if I go above a couple of levels on a second modifier.

Comment: In 3.5 it works fluently.

Comment: 3.5.1 crashes when I increase the second modifier to level 5 here but is a bit more responsive than 3.6 at lower levels.

Comment: Check if simplify is not on by default, also try portable Blender, if that's not the case, it's probably a bug to report

Comment: @joshsanfelici you said that you reinstalled 3.6.4 from scratch. Did you try that after either renaming, or moving the 3.6 folder out of the Users->your user name->AppData->Roaming->Blender Foundation->Blender folder? I don't know if it would make any difference, but you might try it. If you were going to do that I would suggest that you don't click on the "use settings from 3.5" or whatever that option says the first time you open the reinstalled Blender.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it was my fault, I had the Simplify option enabled with a max subdivision level on 1.

Sorry for this stupid mistake.